# Definition of tautological vector bundle

Tags: vector-bundles, grassmannians

Could you please give a detailed definition (or construction)of tautological vector bundle of Grassmannian over arbitrary base scheme? Thank you in advance!

Comment: This site is for questions of math research, please consider using [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ravi Vakil, [The Rising Sea](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/), 16.7 *The Grassmannian as a moduli space*, p. 442.

Comment: Thank you! By the way, on section 21.4.10 of his book, what is the exact meaning of that short exact sequence in order to define tautological vector bundle ?

Comment: It is not clear to me what aspect of the short exact sequence is not clear to you. Intuitively, each fiber of the first term is a vector subspace of $V$ (or really of the dual of $V$, the way he sets it up), while each fiber of the third term is the quotient of $V$ (or of the dual space, again) by that subspace.